# ASP.NET MVC Identity password RequiredLength

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

How can I make RequiredLength of identity to work. I already try to change the value of RequiredLength to 10, but i still can register using 6 password. when i try to change it to RequiredLength to 5, it doesnt work. It said password need to be atleast 6 length. I also modified the viewmodels but same thing happen, I think it was stuck in RequiredLength = 6. I also try to clean and rebuild my project.

```
manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
{
    RequiredLength = 10,
    RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
    RequireDigit = false,
    RequireLowercase = false,
    RequireUppercase = false,
};
```

**EDIT:** working on register account, but not working on change password

Comment: are you using the default mvc5 template with individual accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use Data Annotation Feature to achieve by decorating the entity field with validator.

```
[Required]
[StringLength(10)]
public string RequiredLength { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewModel add an attribute to your Password property:

```
[MinLength(10,ErrorMessage = "Minimum length of 10 characters is required")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

On your post method in the controller check for `ModelState.IsValid`:

```
public ActionResult Login(YourLoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Your Login logic here
    }
    else
    {
        return View(model)
    }
}
```

Finally in your view add `ValidationSummary` to display error:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary("")
```

Answer (score 1):

in the `AccountViewModels.cs` at the `RegisterViewModel` class, by the attribute:

`[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]`

change to:

`[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 10)]`

and also change it at the `ResetPasswordViewModel`